# When operating game using a 2d array in C it goes in the improper direction

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, 2d, cs50

I was creating a game of fifteen and it wouldn't work due to the fact when I iterate in the move method both of the if statements make it go up instead of up and down. Due to this I cannot proceed and add further complexity to the program. Sorry if the question ends up being easy I'm new to coding and am trying to improve but some little things catch me here and there. Thank you for your time, and here is the code: (Although the problem lies in the Move() method (IMO) )

```
/**
 * fifteen.c
 *
 * Implements Game of Fifteen (generalized to d x d).
 *
 * Usage: fifteen d
 *
 * whereby the board's dimensions are to be d x d,
 * where d must be in [DIM_MIN,DIM_MAX]
 *
 * Note that usleep is obsolete, but it offers more granularity than
 * sleep and is simpler to use than nanosleep; `man usleep` for more.
 */

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
// constants
#define DIM_MIN 3
#define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

// dimensions
int d;

// prototypes
void clear(void);
void greet(void);
void init(void);
void draw(void);
bool move(int tile);
bool won(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  // ensure proper usage
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: fifteen d\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // ensure valid dimensions
  d = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (d < DIM_MIN || d > DIM_MAX)
  {
    printf("Board must be between %i x %i and %i x %i, inclusive.\n",
        DIM_MIN, DIM_MIN, DIM_MAX, DIM_MAX);
    return 2;
  }

  // open log
  FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
  if (file == NULL)
  {
    return 3;
  }

  // greet user with instructions
  greet();

  // initialize the board
  init();

  // accept moves until game is won
  while (true)
  {
    // clear the screen
    clear();

    // draw the current state of the board
    draw();

    // log the current state of the board (for testing)
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
      {
        fprintf(file, "%i", board[i][j]);
        if (j < d - 1)
        {
          fprintf(file, "|");
        }
      }
      fprintf(file, "\n");
    }
    fflush(file);

    // check for win
    if (won())
    {
      printf("ftw!\n");
      break;
    }

    // prompt for move
    printf("Tile to move: ");
    int tile = get_int();

    // quit if user inputs 0 (for testing)
    if (tile == 0)
    {
      break;
    }

    // log move (for testing)
    fprintf(file, "%i\n", tile);
    fflush(file);

    // move if possible, else report illegality
    if (!move(tile))
    {
      printf("\nIllegal move.\n");
      usleep(500000);
    }

    // sleep thread for animation's sake
    usleep(500000);
  }

  // close log
  fclose(file);

  // success
  return 0;
}

/**
 * Clears screen using ANSI escape sequences.
 */
void clear(void)
{
  printf("\033[2J");
  printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Greets player.
 */
void greet(void)
{
  clear();
  printf("WELCOME TO GAME OF FIFTEEN\n");
  usleep(2000000);
}

/**
 * Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
 * (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).
 */
void init(void)
{
  int c = (d*d) - 1;

  if (d % 2 == 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i<d; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j<d; j++)
      {
        board[i][j] = c;
        /*
        if (i == d-1 && j == d-1) {
          board[i][j] = 0;
        } */
        if (c == 2)
        {
          board[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else if (c == 1)
        {
          board[i][j] = 2;
        }
        c--;
      }
    }   
  }
  else {
    for (int i = 0; i<d; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j<d; j++)
      {
        board[i][j] = c;
        c--;
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Prints the board in its current state.
 */
void draw(void)
{
  string empty = " _ ";
  for (int i = 0; i<d; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x<d; x++)
    {
   /* if (d % d > 0 && x == d-1 && i == d-1)
      {
        printf("_");
      }
      else { */
      //printf("%d \n", board[i][x]);
      if (board[i][x] != 0) {
      printf("%2i", board[i][x]);
      printf("|");}
      else {
        printf("%s", empty);
      }
      if (x == d-1)
      {
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
}

//All Good Above!

/**
 * If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
 * returns false.
 */
bool move(int tile)
{
  int change;
  printf("Up , down, right , left?");
  string movement = get_string();

  //does not move when it is exchanging with blnk
  //also does not move if beyond range of array -->

  for (int i = 0; i<d; i++) { //rows
    for (int x = 0; x<d; x++) //cols
    {
      if (tile == board[i][x]  && (strcmp(movement,"Up") || strcmp(movement,"up")))
      {
        change = board[i][x];
        board[i][x] = board[i-1][x];
        board[i-1][x] = change;
        return true;
      }
      else if (tile == board[i][x] && (strcmp(movement,"Down") || strcmp(movement,"down")))
      {
        change = board[i][x];
        board[i][x] = board[i+1][x];
        board[i+1][x] = change;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

/**
 * Returns true if game is won (i.e., board is in winning configuration),
 * else false.
 */
bool won(void)
{ //not done //dont worry about 
  int c = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x<d; x++)
    {
      c++;
      if (board[i][x] == c)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
      c++;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh. Have a look at doc. of `strcmp()`. It returns 0 for **equal** and non-0 otherwise. The "thumb rule to remember": If str1 == str2 => `strcmp(str1, str2) == 0`.

Comment: The reason why it does: it returns < 0 for 1st arg. before 2nd arg, and > 0 for 1st arg. after 2nd arg.

Comment: Hence the more general "thumb rule to remember": If str1 _R_ str2 => `strcmp(str1, str2)` _R_ `0` where _R_ might be `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=`.

Comment: Could replace the 2 calls to `strcmp` with `strcasecmp` which would ignore the case of the input

Comment: Please enjoy the exerience that indenting correctly and removing useless white space and empty lines (not all, only the useless) makes it actually eaiser to find and understand logical problems in code.